# Delete only one step in the middle of history (Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, history

Is it possible to delete only one step in the middle of history (keeping all steps after it) without juggling with multiple files?

Comment: Why would you possibly need to do that??!! even if you could, the step before it would include that!!

Comment: You can work in PS in such a way that most of the actions are still alive (live effects, adjustment layers, vector masks etc.) But there are situations where you are not satisfied with some of clone stamp clicks, or brush strokes. And you realize that 15 minutes ( and few dozen of steps) later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to delete a step in your history without deleting all steps after it.

Comment: Thanks, at least  now I know for sure that there is no such an option :)

Comment: My pleasure. :) I've totally been there (Oh wait, I didn't want to add that effect, but I want to keep the scale transform!), but for most histories, all the steps are needed to get to the current state. It would be a total mess if users could delete intermediate actions.

Comment: This answer is wrong and has been since it was answered. I'll add the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Despite the answers here saying otherwise, yes you can delete one step in your history.

You do this by selecting the fly-out menu button in the history panel then doing `History Options > Allow Non-linear History`. Then you can delete any step in your history without it deleting any subsequents steps after it.

It's a real shame this answer has over 6k views stating you can't do this.

Comment: It’s a shame you weren’t here 5 years ago to answer it the first time. ;) Good catch!

Comment: Its not self evident that people who use a tool for years know everything in said tool. But yes i knew this but didnt know this question existed

Comment: I tried this, but it did not do want I wanted. It deletes the step from the history, but does not delete the operation. I had done a select and clear on part of an image, that I regretted later in the process. I was hoping deleting the step would delete the action and then replay everything after that. But apparently it just deleted the step, so you could not go back to it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

No, not possible. History only stores the list of steps, not its actions.

Comment: I know that this idea is actually more complicated that it looks at first glance, because some of the later steps could be dependable of the step which should be deleted. But I hoped that PS can delete only dependable steps or something...